# How does the curve function in R work? - Example of curve function

Tags: r, plot, arguments, curve

How does the following code work? I got the example when I was reading the help line of R `?curve`. But i have not understood this.

```
  for(ll in c("", "x", "y", "xy"))
     curve(log(1+x), 1, 100, log = ll,
        sub = paste("log= '", ll, "'", sep = ""))
```

Particularly , I am accustomed to numeric values as arguments inside the `for-loop` as,

```
  for(ll in 1:10)
```

But what is the following command saying:

```
  for(ll in c("","x","y","xy"))
```

`c("","x","y","xy")` looks like a string vector? How does `c("","x","y","xy")` work inside `curve`
function  as `log(1+x)`[what is x here? the string "x"? in `c("","x","y","xy")`] and `log=ll` ?

Comment: The `log(1+x)` part in curve is not directly affected by the loop. As you see, `ll` iterates through the character vector `c("","x","y","xy")` and is supplied to the `log` parameter inside `curve`. The parameter description is: `The value of log is used both to specify the plot axes (unless add = TRUE) and how ‘equally spaced’ is interpreted: if the x component indicates log-scaling, the points at which the expression or function is plotted are equally spaced on log scale.` So if you define for example, `log = "x"` it means your x axis will be displayed logarithmically.

Comment: The short answer is that the parameter `ll` ia only being passed to formal arguments in `curve` that "expect" (or more accurately are defined as receiving) character values.

Comment: `for (letter in c("a", "b", "c")) print(letter)`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there are no answers on stack overflow about how the `curve` function in R works and especially about the `log` argument so this might be a good chance to delve into it a bit more (I liked the question btw):

**First of all the easy part:**

`c("","x","y","xy")` is a string vector or more formally a character vector.

`for(ll in c("","x","y","xy"))` will start a loop of 4 iterations and each time `ll` will be `'','x','y','xy'` respectively. Unfortunately, the way this example is built you will only see the last one plotted which is for `ll = 'xy'`.

**Let's dive into the source code of the `curve` function to answer the rest:**

- First of all the what does the `x` represent in `log(1+x)`?

`log(1+x)` is a function. `x` represents a vector of numbers that gets created inside the `curve` function in the following part (from source code):

```
 x <- exp(seq.int(log(from), log(to), length.out = n)) #if the log argument is 'x' or
 x <- seq.int(from, to, length.out = n)               #if the log argument is not 'x' 
 #in  our case from and to are 1 and 100 respectively
```

As long as the `n` argument is the default the `x` vector will contain 101 elements. Obviously the `x` in `log(1+x)` is totally different to the 'x' in the `log` argument.

as for `y` it is always created as (from source code):

```
 y <- eval(expr, envir = ll, enclos = parent.frame()) #where expr is in this case log(1+x), the others are not important to analyse now.
 #i.e. you get a y value for each x value on the x vector which was calculated just previously
```

- Second, what is the purpose of the `log` argument?

The `log` argument decides which of the `x` or `y` axis will be logged. The x-axis if `'x'` is the `log` argument, y-axis if `'y'` is the `log` argument, both axis if `'xy'` is the `log` argument and no log-scale if the `log` argument is `''`.

It needs to be mentioned here that the log of either x or y axis is being calculated in the `plot` function in the `curve` function, that is the `curve` function is only a wrapper for the `plot` function.

Having said the above this is why if the `log` argument is 'x' (see above) the exponential of the log values of the vector x are calculated so that they will return to the logged ones inside the `plot` function.

P.S. the source code for the `curve` function can be seen with typing `graphics::curve` on the console.

I hope this makes a bit of sense now!